# GameClosure IOS ImageView prolem

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, game-engine, gameclosure

I have a problem with `iOS` (iPhone and iPad) but not in android devices:

I have roughly 50 ImageViews loaded, this causes an infinite `loop` where all images are reloaded so I see flashing images.

I tried with and without this code in `Application.js`, nothing changed.

```
this.engine.updateOpts({
        logsEnabled: true,
        noTimestep: false,
        noReflow: true,
        showFPS: true,
        resizeRootView: false,
        preload: ['resources/images']
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried submitting a bug or the IRC channel?